# Custom (convolutional) connections between two Keras layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am looking for a possibility to define custom interconnections between two Keras layers. I want to mimic a convolutional behavior with a custom and varying number of inputs. The following simplified example, sketched below, illustrates my needs. Inputs 0, 1, and 2 shall be combined into a single cell. Input 3 shall be considered alone and 4 and 5 shall be combined as well. In the example, the input groups (0, 1, 2), (3), and (4, 5) are always combined in one neuron. A further step would be a combination in several neurons (e.g. inputs 0, 1, and 2 into two hidden layer neurons).

```
       X        Output layer
    /  |  \
  X    X   X    Hidden layer
 /|\   |  / \
X X X  X  X X   Input layer
0 1 2  3  4 5
```

I did not find a straight-forward solution to this problem in the Keras documentation or maybe I am looking at the wrong places. Convolutional layers are always expecting a fixed number of input values. This problems seems not to complex to me. I did not provide any code, because there is nothing worth sharing yet. However, I will update the question with code when I find a working solution.

Maybe some background for this problem. I split up categorical values into hot vectors. For instance, a categorical values with three manifestations 'a', 'b', 'c' into (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), and (0, 0, 1). These are fed into a neural network alongside other values. Leading to inputs (1, 0, 0, X, X, X), (0, 1, 0, X, X, X), and (0, 0, 1, X, X, X) for the above example network (X for an arbitrary value). When I have a fully connected layer now, the network looses the information that the inputs 0, 1, and 2 actually originated from the same variable and should be considered together. With the architecture above I want to ensure that the network considers these values together before correlating them with other variables. I hope this make sense, if not please let me know why.

Update:
The answer supplied a good code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Keras [`functional API`](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

You can define three inputs to your network and then build the model on top of that as you like.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv1D, Concatenate
x = Input(shape=(None, 3))
y = Input(shape=(None, 1))
z = Input(shape=(None, 2))
conv_x = Conv1D(...)(x)
conv_y = Conv1D(...)(y)
conv_z = Conv1D(...)(z)
conv = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv_x, conv_y, conv_z])
```

Comment: Okay that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.